# intellij auto import custom buildfile

Tags: java, build, intellij-plugin

I dislike the build tools that exist for Java. So I wrote my own. But there is one feature that it doesn't have yet; auto-import of changes into the IntelliJ project.

I'm having trouble finding information on how to do this. Tutorials on how to write IntelliJ plugins throw tons of useless stuff at me (creating UI for example).

I know this isn't your typical stackoverflow I-have-a-bug question but I'm quite lost and could use a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know when a certian file was changed and auto-import information from this file you can use VirtualFileManager.addVirtualFileListener().
Or even use fileDocumentManagerListener extension point. Whatever suits your needs more.

Comment: Nice :). I was actually thinking I would have to use Java's WatchService to do this part. This seems like a better option. The API for this is confusing though. The method takes a VirtualFileListener, and I've found the VirtualFileAdapter to make things easier. But I don't see where I register the specific file to watch. Does this listener get events for all the files that change inside the module?

Answer (score 0):

So far I've managed to create a simple IntelliJ plugin. The start is fairly simple. IntelliJ has the plugin project skeleton built in. File->new Project is enough there.

From there I've created a class that implements ModuleComponent. The documentation here (https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_components.html) says it will be loaded whenever a module is opened.

To get it to work I had to add this stuff in the plugin.xml:

```
<module-components>
  <component>
    <interface-class>packagename.ClassName</interface-class>
    <implementation-class>packagename.ClassName</implementation-class>
  </component>
</module-components>
```

The documentation manages to hide this next step but its possible to give the ModuleComponent a constructor like so:

```
public ClassName(final Module module) {}
```

This should give me an instance of the Module class to read values from and to modify the way I need.
As it turns out IntelliJ makes it difficult to figure out how to do things. There is no Javadoc for example. People seem to suggest reading the source code. Weird..

A quick look through the methods of Module didn't really help me much. Google let me know that in order to make changes to the Module I could do the following:

```
ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module).getModifiableModel()
```

I can call several methods on this model and finally call .commit() when I'm done to persist the changes. The ModifiableRootModel has two methods that look very promissing:

```
ModifiableRootModel.addModuleOrderEntry()
ModifiableRootModel.addLibraryEntry()
```

The first takes a Module instance. I'm hoping that if I add the correct Module this will allow me to well, add modules :). I can think of two situations here. First, the module is already loaded in the project, in which case I will need to find it and add it. And second, the module is not loaded yet so I will need to tell IntelliJ to load it and add it to the project.

The second method takes a Library instance. Just new Library() doesn't work, and google isn't very helpful here. From my buildfile I can extract the groupId:artifactId:version:scope value. So I'll need a way to turn those strings into a Library that works.

This is how far I've gotten so far. Current problems are:

- I need to find the already loaded modules so I can find the one I'm linking to
- I need a way to add a module to the project if it hasn't been loaded yet
- I need a way to turn a maven style dependency into a Library object so I can add it to the module
- I need a way to list all the existing modules and libraries so I don't end up adding duplicates